# Unespected runtime Error when try to send document

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have new Lotus Domino Server 8.5.3 FP1 UP1 (Windows 2008 64bit).

I have created an xpages sample copied from help that send mail.

```
var doc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
doc.replaceItemValue("form", "Memo");
doc.replaceItemValue("sendTo", "daniel.recio@slug.es");
doc.replaceItemValue("subject", "hi there!");
doc.replaceItemValue("body", "content here");
doc.send();
```

But i have Unespected runtime Error

Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=6, col=5: [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method **NotesDocument.send()** null

▼ Stack Trace
javax.faces.FacesException: Error while executing JavaScript action expression
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:102)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:250)

I have full uninstalled this server, and reinstall with same error.

In other testing server works, but in this server my lotus designer was 8.5.2 + Ext Lib and now is 8.5.3 FP1 UP1.

can you help me??

Thanks for all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is likely because the server is unable to actually send the message. Server side, when the server can not route the message, it causes an exception. Make sure your server can successfully route mail messages on its own, then your error will likely go away.

Comment: Thanks, but if i open Inotes mailbox, i can send mails, internals, and externals, to adyacent domains, and non adyacents domains.

Im lose

Comment: That does not necessarily mean the server can actually send the mail. Its a difference, but a subtle one. Write a lotus script agent to send the message the same way and see if it successfully transmits it.

Comment: Thanks, tomorrow i will write lotusscript agent and post feedback.

Comment: SOLVED, THANKS A LOT.

Problem was that server do not resolve himself because DNS point other IP. When I changed SMTPFULLHOSTNAME notes.ini (PORTS TAB in Document Server and host name in Basic Tab) with his IP then all works perfectly (lotusScript and Xpages).

Answer (score 1):

Check the ACL and make sure that you (or anonymous if you are testing as anonymous) have access to create documents. My guess is that this is what causes NotesDocument to be null.

Also, have a look at the /domino/workspace/logs/error-log-0.xml file located in the Domino data directory for additional explanation of the error.

Comment: Thanks for response, but ACL has Anonymous Manager, Default Manager, and error-log-0.xml only have same error that stack trace

Comment: No need to uninstall and reinstall the server. Try to create a new blank db with full access for anonymous and add an XPage with a button that does just the mail send logic.

Comment: Thansk, i tried it, and i upload my customize filesendr database (working in other servers), and standar filesendr database. And same error in .send method.

Comment: SOLVED, THANKS A LOT. Problem was that server do not resolve himself because DNS point other IP. When I changed SMTPFULLHOSTNAME notes.ini (PORTS TAB in Document Server and host name in Basic Tab) with his IP then all works perfectly (lotusScript and Xpages).

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the type cast on the first line and try it again. I've seen issues before where the cast causes problems. So, your code should look like this:

```
 var doc = database.createDocument();
 doc.replaceItemValue("form", "Memo");
 doc.replaceItemValue("sendTo", "daniel.recio@slug.es");
 doc.replaceItemValue("subject", "hi there!");
 doc.replaceItemValue("body", "content here");
 doc.send();
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try and post response

Comment: Same error, and just uninstall server, FIX Pack and Upgrade PAck. Installed New Server domino 8.5.3 without Fixes and UP and have same error.
Thanks

Comment: SOLVED, THANKS A LOT. Problem was that server do not resolve himself because DNS point other IP. When I changed SMTPFULLHOSTNAME notes.ini (PORTS TAB in Document Server and host name in Basic Tab) with his IP then all works perfectly (lotusScript and Xpages).

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same code running in my app except I used appendItemValue instead of replaceItemValue and it works fine. I am on 8.5.3 FP1 UP1 also. Not sure what the difference internally would be but it is something to try.

Comment: Thanks, after two installs and reinstalls, tomorrow i will try on new server machine.

Comment: SOLVED, THANKS A LOT. Problem was that server do not resolve himself because DNS point other IP. When I changed SMTPFULLHOSTNAME notes.ini (PORTS TAB in Document Server and host name in Basic Tab) with his IP then all works perfectly (lotusScript and Xpages).

Answer (score 0):

Is the code is working ob your local machine (if you open a local replica in your browser)?

Perhaps the server document is corrupted: Try recreate it. This fixed the same issue for one of my customers. Another idea is to recreate the default view in the Database.

**EDIT:**
And could you please check the Stacktrace? The last block contains perhaps more informations. There should be some lines like these:

```
    lotus.domino.local.Document.Nsend(Native Method)
    lotus.domino.local.Document.send(Unknown Source)
```

Please post the NotesException *above* these lines.

Comment: SOLVED, THANKS A LOT. Problem was that server do not resolve himself because DNS point other IP. When I changed SMTPFULLHOSTNAME notes.ini (PORTS TAB in Document Server and host name in Basic Tab) with his IP then all works perfectly (lotusScript and Xpages).